# DiscordBot Python

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Подскажите пожалуйста я хочу сделать discord бота который при вводе команды *add (SteamID64) (название роли) что бы он создавал в текстовом документе слова  - (SteamID64)@steam: admin
это получается команда должна в конфигах игры на моём сервере выдавать игроку роль что бы после *add можно было написать SteamID64 игрока которому я хочу заменить роль и название роли, что бы например название роли было ml то бот бы вписывал в документ  - (SteamID64)@steam: moderator, а когда пишу adm то - (SteamID64)@steam: admin. Извините если как то странно выразился. И это всё на Python.

Answer (score -1):

[Вот](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/tree/master/examples) примеры кода на **nextcord**. Там есть всё что вам надо. Если что-то будет не понятно, [вот](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/) документация.